# toggle an image to a html map image by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

first of all I wanted to know if it is possible?

I want to change a picture inside a div while mouse is hover on the div to another picture which is a html imagemap.

if it is why this code does not work?

```
<script>
        function chgImg(x) {
            x.src = "2.jpg";
            x.write('&lt;img src=&quot;Untitled&quot; width=&quot;320&quot; height=&quot;427&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; usemap=&quot;#map&quot; /&gt;');

            x.write('&lt;map name=&quot;map&quot;&gt;');
            x.write('&lt;area shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;45,85,104,143&quot; href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot; &gt;');
            x.write('&lt;area shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;204,40,299,120&quot; href=&quot;http://www.yahoo.com&quot; &gt;');
            x.write('&lt;area shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;51,296,121,368&quot; href=&quot;http://www.imdb.com&quot; &gt;');
            x.write('&lt;/map&gt;');
        }

        function originImg(x) {
            x.src = "1.jpg";
        }
    </script>
```

I changed quote , less than and greater than by html identities in order to evade nested quotes in the java script function.
thank you for your help.

Comment: i don think you are supposed to escape the <> signs, on the contrary, if you do so they are considered text, not html. morevoer, you are writing a img tag inside an img tag? are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: I want to change a picture inside a div while mouse is hover on the div to another picture which is a html imagemap.

Comment: `x.src` tends to indicate that x is an img, but your comment suggests you are working on a div. which one is it ?

Comment: it indicates im a noob to :D.

Comment: then i should point to div and change its background when a mous pointer hovers on it?

Comment: Also, the map does not need to be added dynamically. Apparently, it can reside statically in your page, only to be referenced when needed by the img tag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x` is an `img` element, the following should suffice :

HTML part:

```
<img onmouseover="chgImg" onmouseout= "originImg" src="1.jpg">
<map name="map">
  <!--You map here-->
</map>
```

Javascript part

```
function chgImg(x) {
    x.src = "2.jpg";
    x.usemap = "map";
}
function originImg(x) {
    x.src = "1.jpg";
    delete x.usemap;
}
```

(Nota : not entirely sure about the last statement. Could be `x.usemap = ""` or `x.usemap = null` or `x.usemap = undefined`)

If you really need to dynamically construct a map for your img, I suggest you take a look at `document.createElement` and `Node.appendChild`, 2 functions that will allow you to add items to the DOM tree in a clean fashion.

I also recommend you use the Mozilla javascript documentation for the reference regarding these 2 DOM functions and all others, as I find it to be the most comprehensive and clear documentation for standart javascript objects and functions.